# How to scan and read MICR code on Bank cheque using OCR scanner or any API available in MobileFirst Platform?

Tags: android, ocr, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-plugin, micr

One of my android projects requires a feature of OCR reader to read the MICR code on the bank cheque leaf in. We have tried a sample code of android native application which is scanning the page and reading the maximum different types of fonts. But when scanning the MICR code, the app is not able to read the number and giving entirely different number. Please suggest if any feature available for OCR scanning in the MobileFirst platform, if possible please share the sample code. Please tell me whether it is possible to read a MICR code through the OCR scanner?

Comment: Are you tied to MobileFirst platform, or you can explore other technologies specialized for payments OCR (including MICR)?

Answer (score 1):

This is not really related to MobileFirst Platform. MobileFirst provides you with an SDK to connection to backend systems with a security layer via Adapters, and an application structure if you've created a Hybrid app.

However the client-side of the application is Cordova based. As such you can use Cordova plug-ins to add missing functionality. For example, this OCR scanner plug-in: https://github.com/rmtheis/android-ocr

If you created a Native app, then this is really completely decoupled from MobileFirst and you need to find native libraries that does what you want, or write one such on your own.